# Hiding Side Nav in Hamburger Menu

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a sidebar, that I would like to collpase on mobile devices, and only be accessed on mobile using a hamburger menu

Using React, what is the best way for me to do so? Would this still be media queriers, or is there an alternate way that would make this type of configuration more seamless?

Please note that I only want the sidebar to collapse on mobile. I do not want to give the user the ability to collpase the sidebar when viewed on desktop.

Sidebar.Js

```
const sidebarNavItems = [
       {
            display: 'Home',
            to: '/'
        
        },
        {
            display: 'Blog',
            to: 'Blog/'
        },
        {
            display: 'Contact Us',
            to: '/contact-us/'
        },
        {
            display: 'Sign Up',
            to: '/sign-up/'
        },
        {
            display: 'Login',
            to: '/sign-in/'
        },
       
    ]

    const Sidebar = () => {
        const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
        const [stepHeight, setStepHeight] = useState(0);
        const sidebarRef = useRef();
        const indicatorRef = useRef();
        const location = useLocation();
    
        useEffect(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const sidebarItem = sidebarRef.current.querySelector('.sidebar__menu__item');
                indicatorRef.current.style.height = `${sidebarItem.clientHeight}px`;
                setStepHeight(sidebarItem.clientHeight);
            }, 50);
        }, []);

         // change active index
    useEffect(() => {
        const curPath = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
        const activeItem = sidebarNavItems.findIndex(item => item.section === curPath);
        setActiveIndex(curPath.length === 0 ? 0 : activeItem);
    }, [location]);
    

    return (
      <div className='sidebar'>
      <div className="sidebar__logo">
      <div><img src = {Logo} alt='Logo'className='Logo' /></div>
      </div>
      <div ref={sidebarRef} className="sidebar__menu">
          <div
              ref={indicatorRef}
              className="sidebar__menu__indicator"
              style={{
                  transform: `translateX(-50%) translateY(${activeIndex * stepHeight}px)`
              }}
          ></div>
          {
              sidebarNavItems.map((item, index) => (
                  <Link to={item.to} key={index}>
                      <div className={`sidebar__menu__item ${activeIndex === index ? 'active' : ''}`}>
                          <div className="sidebar__menu__item__icon">
                              {item.icon}
                          </div>
                          <div className="sidebar__menu__item__text">
                              {item.display}
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </Link>
              ))
          }
      </div>
  </div>);
};
```

Here is the Sidebar.CSS

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 20vw;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.sidebar__logo {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
}
.sidebar__menu {
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar__menu__item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    place-content: flex-start;
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #555;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar__menu__item.active {
    color: #fff;
}
.sidebar__menu__item__icon {
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
.sidebar__menu__item__icon i {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
}
.sidebar__menu__indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #FD954E;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: You can go both ways , either define a className in CSS with media queries or use javascript to get screen.width or get the device and assing to a variable and depending on this variable you shoose to return the element or not , even more you can do both .

Comment: @ChakibSalah can you provide code anwer?

Comment: I think you should be able to do so after watching this tut (this is plain JS but you can convert it to React by using states etc).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbBMp6yUXO0&t=2397s